# Dplyr: using summarise across to take mean of columns only if row value > 0

Tags: r, dplyr, mean, summarize, across

I have a dataframe of gene expression scores (cells x genes). I also have the cluster that each cell belongs to in stored as a column.

I want to calculate the mean expression values per cluster for a group of genes (columns), however, I only want to include values > 0 in these calculations.

My attempt at this is as follows:

```
test <- gene_scores_df2 %>% 
  select(all_of(gene_list), Clusters) %>%
  group_by(Clusters) %>%
  summarize(across(c(1:13), ~mean(. > 0)))
```

This produces the following tibble:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 14
   Clusters SLC17A7  GAD1  GAD2 SLC32A1  GLI3   TNC PROX1  SCGN   LHX6 NXPH1 MEIS2 ZFHX3     C3
   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 C1         0.611 0.605 0.817   0.850 0.979 0.590 0.725 0.434 0.275  0.728 0.949 0.886 0.332 
 2 C10        0.484 0.401 0.434   0.401 0.791 0.387 0.431 0.362 0.204  0.652 0.715 0.580 0.186 
 3 C11        0.495 0.5   0.538   0.412 0.847 0.437 0.516 0.453 0.187  0.764 0.804 0.640 0.160 
 4 C12        0.807 0.626 0.559   0.703 0.942 0.448 0.644 0.366 0.403  0.702 0.917 0.859 0.228 
 5 C13        0.489 0.578 0.709   0.719 0.796 0.409 0.565 0.371 0.367  0.773 0.716 0.776 0.169 
 6 C14        0.541 0.347 0.330   0.388 0.731 0.281 0.438 0.279 0.198  0.577 0.777 0.633 0.128 
 7 C15        0.152 0.306 0.337   0.198 0.629 0.304 0.331 0.179 0.132  0.496 0.509 0.405 0.0556
 8 C16        0.402 0.422 0.542   0.418 0.813 0.514 0.614 0.287 0.267  0.729 0.574 0.737 0.279 
 9 C2         0.152 0.480 0.458   0.297 0.883 0.423 0.511 0.195 0.152  0.722 0.692 0.598 0.0632
10 C3         0.585 0.679 0.659   0.711 0.996 0.886 0.801 0.297 0.305  0.789 0.992 0.963 0.346 
11 C4         0.567 0.756 0.893   0.940 0.892 0.334 0.797 0.750 0.376  0.686 0.897 0.885 0.240 
12 C5         0.220 0.516 0.560   0.625 0.673 0.250 0.466 0.275 0.358  0.590 0.571 0.641 0.112 
13 C6         0.558 0.908 0.836   0.973 0.725 0.280 0.830 0.642 0.871  0.927 0.830 0.916 0.202 
14 C7         0.380 0.743 0.749   0.772 0.825 0.415 0.480 0.211 0.199  0.614 0.860 0.901 0.135 
15 C8         0.616 0.348 0.312   0.334 0.749 0.271 0.451 0.520 0.129  0.542 0.743 0.735 0.147 
16 C9         0.406 0.381 0.400   0.265 0.679 0.266 0.465 0.233 0.0820 0.648 0.565 0.557 0.119
```

However, when I check this against (what I assume is) a similar procedure on a single column I get different mean values.

Here is the code for SLC1747:

```
gene_scores_df2 %>% 
  select(SLC17A7, Clusters) %>%
  group_by(Clusters) %>%
  filter(SLC17A7 > 0) %>%
  summarize(SLC17A7 = mean(SLC17A7))
```

And the result:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 2
   Clusters SLC17A7
   <chr>      <dbl>
 1 C1         0.780
 2 C10        1.42 
 3 C11        1.21 
 4 C12        1.64 
 5 C13        1.09 
 6 C14        1.83 
 7 C15        1.61 
 8 C16        0.968
 9 C2         1.09 
10 C3         0.512
11 C4         0.920
12 C5         1.53 
13 C6         0.814
14 C7         1.22 
15 C8         2.24 
16 C9         1.72
```

I'm unsure what exactly is wrong with the first attempt above.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

---

Code snippet for original df for

```
# First 20 cols of:
gene_scores_df2 %>% 
       select(all_of(gene_list), Clusters) %>%
       group_by(Clusters)

structure(list(SLC17A7 = c(0.273, 0.722, 0.699, 0.71, 0.333, 
0.674, 0.63, 0.481, 0.274, 0.981, 0.586, 0.401, 0.325, 0.583, 
0, 0.348, 0.287, 0, 0.295, 0.351), GAD1 = c(0.355, 0.392, 0.455, 
0.34, 0.108, 1.169, 0, 0.426, 2.219, 0.099, 1.16, 0.332, 0.404, 
0.284, 0, 5.297, 0.518, 0.027, 1.19, 0.346), GAD2 = c(0.12, 0.562, 
0.337, 0.49, 0.095, 0.958, 0.09, 1.518, 1.464, 0.175, 0.419, 
0.536, 0.501, 1.103, 0.343, 0, 0.247, 0, 0.635, 0.906), SLC32A1 = c(0, 
0.97, 0.067, 0.999, 0.224, 1.04, 0, 2.569, 1.544, 0.059, 2.177, 
3.227, 3.603, 1.229, 0.102, 2.421, 0.055, 0.826, 2.646, 0.228
), GLI3 = c(1.527, 0.487, 0.341, 3.352, 0.346, 0.694, 1.395, 
0.767, 1.334, 1.373, 1.7, 2.216, 0.394, 1.029, 1.235, 0.55, 2.043, 
4.469, 2.901, 4.139), TNC = c(0, 0, 0.448, 0.03, 1.377, 0.045, 
0, 0.169, 0.123, 0, 0.188, 0.075, 0, 1.074, 0, 1.272, 0.124, 
0.505, 0.173, 0.889), PROX1 = c(0, 0.075, 0.167, 0.782, 0.802, 
0.561, 0.098, 0.734, 0.448, 1.645, 0.735, 0.795, 0.102, 0.317, 
0.124, 0.324, 0.352, 0.236, 0.826, 0.308), SCGN = c(0.696, 0.234, 
0, 0.202, 0.059, 0.162, 0, 0.653, 0.383, 0.42, 0.094, 0.779, 
0.228, 0.248, 0.171, 0.089, 0.081, 0.026, 0.159, 0), LHX6 = c(0, 
0, 0.134, 0.1, 0.829, 1.489, 0, 0.38, 0.526, 0.117, 0, 0.205, 
0.299, 2.235, 0, 1.335, 0, 0.115, 0.454, 0.108), NXPH1 = c(0.792, 
0.143, 0.175, 0.658, 0, 1.034, 1.798, 0.219, 0.896, 0.249, 1.336, 
1.507, 0.26, 0.242, 1.235, 2.16, 0.235, 0.349, 1.297, 2.234), 
    MEIS2 = c(4.337, 0.559, 0.978, 1.972, 0.964, 0.657, 0.162, 
    0.827, 0.882, 0.157, 1.494, 1.171, 2.524, 2.458, 0.205, 0.448, 
    2.027, 4.767, 1.514, 2.077), ZFHX3 = c(1.48, 1.38, 2.323, 
    1.039, 1.343, 1.354, 0.238, 1.224, 1.676, 0.811, 0.316, 2.012, 
    2.298, 1.869, 0.201, 0.176, 1.829, 1.081, 0.522, 0.959), 
    C3 = c(0.52, 0.527, 0, 0.073, 0, 0.15, 0.094, 0.315, 0.174, 
    0, 0, 0.17, 0.165, 0, 0.237, 0, 0.091, 0.095, 0, 0.081), 
    Clusters = c("C12", "C5", "C13", "C4", "C12", "C13", "C13", 
    "C4", "C6", "C8", "C4", "C4", "C4", "C12", "C5", "C6", "C1", 
    "C3", "C4", "C3")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(
    Clusters = c("C1", "C12", "C13", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", 
    "C8"), .rows = structure(list(17L, c(1L, 5L, 14L), c(3L, 
    6L, 7L), c(18L, 20L), c(4L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 19L), c(2L, 
    15L), c(9L, 16L), 10L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: `~mean(. > 0)` will turn the data into TRUE FALSE and not filter the data,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(Clusters) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), ~mean(.[. > 0])))
```

`~mean(. > 0)` checks if an element is greater 0 or not and thus returns TRUE/FALSE and then gives you the mean of the underlying 0/1's. Instead you want to filter each column which can be achieved with the usual `[]` approach